# SQL Server create 'lean' database

Tags: sql-server, azure

Is there a way in SQL Server to create a new database without the 1000 or so ancillary items that it usually creates (such as all the views, system databases, external relations, etc. etc.) Or is this part of the initialization of the SQL Server database and there isn't a choice?

My command is merely:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.
SQL uses the model database, and essentially copies it for any database that you create. If you want to change any of the default objects created in any new database, then you can try to modify the model database accordingly. However, you will not be able to remove the system objects. (Not without breaking SQL in some way, anyway.)